# Noise in thin gaps between meshes in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I´m new at this and Im out of my depth. The problem is this: rendering in cycles, at some places of the model, specially in the thin gaps between different meshes (marked red), I get a lot of noise. See image attached. I´ve raised the samples, the bounces, etc... and it alleviates the problem but still persist. What am I doing wrong? Do I need to add even more samples? That would a pain.

[image: Panel gaps marked in red appear noisier and darker in the render]

I´ll add the render, world and material settings. I hope you spot something inusual. The file is quite heavy, so I´ll only waste your bandwidht as a last resort.

I´ve already tried to disable the bump mapping, in case it was that causing any normal problem or something, but it didn´t work.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It could be that you are using too much ambient occlusion, but it is hard to guess from the current information on the question.

Comment: I already have ambient occlusion off.

Comment: It would help if you add more details to your question and consider adding a link to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this checkbox, I'm just wondering if it's the smoothing.

[image]

Edited to add:  This was not the answer in this case, but shade smooth can produce effects somewhat like this as seen in this example:

[image]

The auto-smooth option defines a cutoff where, below this angle, normals will be smoothed between the two faces.  For angles above this threshold the hard edge is retained.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but no, it didn´t work.

Comment: Hi Allen. Maybe instead of deleting your answer, you could simply add some details what this influences and why this could solve the problem. Other askers might find this answer helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I've expanded.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, I´ve found the issue: the subsurface scaterring radius of the material was too high. Lowering it minimized the problem.

I was trying to emulate a real paint, that has a base color and a transparent glossy lacquer over it. To do so I was using subsurface color. In the end I abandoned the whole idea, as the gain was unnoticeable vs using a simple glossy material.